# How can I swap the position of an icon and text of an <a> tag

Tags: html, css

I have a toggle button on my page that is created by my document generation system. The generated HTML is

```
<a href="#" ><img  src="toggleIcon" class="toggler"> toggle text</a>
```

On the page, this is rendered with the toggleIcon (>) on the left and the toggle text immediately to the right. It looks like this

```
 > toggle text
```

I need to use CSS so that toggle icon is on the right so it looks like this

```
 toggle text >
```

I tried to do

```
.toggler {
   float:right;
}
```

but this put the icon on the left and overlapping (in z) of the toggle text (using Windows 10 Chrome)

I can't change the HTML, I have a class on the  but not on the toggle text - how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot control HTML...

- Make your `<a>` **relative** and add **padding** as the space for the icon
- Make your `<img>` **absolute** and move it to the right

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 30px; /* make space for the toggle icon */
  outline: 1px solid red; /* just to see what we'rer doing */
}

a img.toggler {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="//placehold.it/18x18/0bf" class="toggler"> toggle text</a>
```

needless to say, you should use a parent class for the above styles, otherwise you'll end up changing every `a` element on the page.